# How do I properly draw a frame with an ILI9341? Arduino

Tags: arduino, drawing, draw, arduino-uno, lcd

I have a [2.8 inch TFT LCD](https://www.adafruit.com/product/1770) from Adafruit driven by an [ILI9341](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/ILI9341.pdf). To draw on the LCD, I use the commands `0x2A` to set the width, `0x2B` to set the height, and `0x2C` to color each pixel (I2C). My problem is that I currently draw the background as a rectangle, and then each rectangle required. This creates a displeasing look since the colors start to mix and create disturbing, angled lines between the smaller rectangles. These are the functions I use to draw:

```
void drawRectangle(long sX, long sY, long eX, long eY, uint16_t clr) {
  send32bitData(0x2A, (sX << 16) | eX);
  send32bitData(0x2B, (sY << 16) | eY);
  oneColor(clr, (eX - sX + 1) * (eY - sY + 1));
}
void oneColor(uint16_t clr, long area) {
  uint8_t hi = clr >> 8;
  uint8_t lo = clr;
  uint8_t dHi = clr >> 6, bHi = clr >> 14, dLo = clr << 2, bLo = clr >> 6;
  sendCommand(0x2C, true);
  PORTC = 0x6;
  for (long i = area; i--; i > 0) {
    PORTC = 0x6;
    PORTD = dHi;
    PORTB = bHi;
    PORTC = 0x2;
    PORTC = 0x6;
    PORTD = dLo;
    PORTB = bLo;
    PORTC = 0x2;
  }
  PORTC = 0x7;
}
```

[Here's a video of that line](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Z9HrF4J4vEtZRASC641pK5MNvqd-7ea2/view?usp=sharing). I'm assuming that I'm drawing wrong. I'd like to keep a huge array with colors for each pixel, but I have an Arduino Uno that 2048 bytes of variable space. If I had that array, then I would draw one rectangle for the whole screen and send each color to the memory. One thing that worked was drawing extremely slow. But, that's slow... I want to draw at ~70 fps while keeping each frame smooth.

Comment: Please add more details to it. This is unclear